# How do I get extra bags in Neverwinter?

Tags: neverwinter

I am playing the Neverwinter online RPG and there's plenty of stuff that one needs to keep in their bags: besides the usual loot, enchantments, runestones, seals, emblems and kits seem to take up 90% of my bags.

After the starting Adventurer's satchel and Adventurer knapsack, how do I obtain more bags?

[image: my bags...]